# How to take full minidump of a web application hosted in IIS without having it recycled?

Tags: iis, web-applications, dump, coredump, minidump

We have a weird situation in production and need to grab a full memory dump. However, writing out the full minidump takes too much time. As a result, IIS recycles the process while the dump is being taken.

We cannot increase this timeout in IIS, because this is a live pod and we do not want other web servers in the farm to be affected.

Is it possible to somehow let IIS know that this particular process should not be recycled? Or any other way to be able to take the full minidump in our circumstances?

The minidump is written to the local file system.

**EDIT 1**

This is not a duplicate of my other question [How to take a minidump of a web application on concrete exception running in a farm with periodic recycling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047264/how-to-take-a-minidump-of-a-web-application-on-concrete-exception-running-in-a-f?noredirect=1#comment100626450_57047264) because the challenges are different. In this question I cope with IIS killing the web process due to inactivity because of the dump having been taken. In the other question the problem is that we cannot attach to a web process and wait for exception - the process will be recycled at one point and we will have to reattach. This is not a human friendly process. Plus it must be replicated across all the machines on the farm. Again, not human friendly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a minidump of a web application on concrete exception running in a farm with periodic recycling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047264/how-to-take-a-minidump-of-a-web-application-on-concrete-exception-running-in-a-f)

Comment: you can use debug diagnostic tool and take full and minidump. you can refer [this document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/08/06/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag/) for how to collect full and the minidump.

Comment: you can disable application pool recycling in iis using select application pool from iis manger-> select advance setting[image](https://imgur.com/a/pAQTJbX). do this setting as shown in the image[image1](https://imgur.com/a/ifstXMj) , [image2](https://imgur.com/a/ghlGgxA)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal - can you confirm that changing these settings on a running pool would not trigger recycle? And that turning recycling back after the dump is taken would work, again without recycling the pool?

Answer (score 0):

1. AppPool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Ping Enabled = false
2. take process memory dump (dump to the fastest drive you have on the system)
3. AppPool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Ping Enabled = true