# How to take a minidump of a web application on concrete exception running in a farm with periodic recycling?

Tags: iis, web-applications, dump, coredump, minidump

- Given: sometimes a certain exception occurs in our web application, which we cannot reproduce, except in production. Unfortunately, there are no telemetry and the logs are not helpful.
- Wanted: minidump when exception happens
- Problem: Running procdump is not helpful, because the process is periodically recycled. A solution is needed that would run ProcDump automatically whenever the web application starts and do it on each and every web server in the farm.

Before engaging in writing an in-house tool to solve this problem I wonder if anything like that already exists. Cannot be that our problem is unique to us.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210

Comment: @LexLi - I know what DebugDiag is. But as far as I know it requires dump files. My problem is generating the dump in the first place. So, what am I missing in your comment?

Comment: By all means, please provide an answer and explain. It is absolutely possible that I do not know how to work with it, but do explain for my and others benefit.

Comment: Tool recommendations should go to a search engine, not here. I already provided you enough to look for.

Comment: I see. I can use it to monitor an application pool. It solves the recycling aspect. What about a farm? We have 50 web servers behind a load balancer on a farm. Does it mean starting 50 instances of Debug Diag one on each web server?

Comment: I suggest you could try to use w3wp as process name for procdump if you have just one application in the web farm.

Comment: Does not work like this. 1. Because we have more than one app. 2. Because procdump would connect to the process and if the process is recycled just die. No resurrection for procdump. As Lex Li suggested Debug Diag does seem to be able to monitor the given app pool, which solves the recycling, but the farm makes it more complicated.